# Empty Result Curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a problem with PHP's cURL returning an empty string with some URL's
i want to coonect this api and i give the empty result, anyone can help me ?

```
<?php
$clTrid="TEST-23233434343";
$nictoken="6661361102210630";
$contact="Test-irnic";

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<command>
<check>
<contact:info xmlns:contact="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/contact-1.0">
<contact:id>' . $contact . '</contact:id>
<contact:pw>' . $nictoken . '</contact:pw>
</contact:authInfo>
</contact:check>
</check>
<clTRID>' . $clTrid . '</clTRID>
</command>
</epp>';
$url = 'https://epp.nic.ir/submit';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
}
else echo " No Error ! "; 
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Sure your XML is correct? `<contact:info...`, `</contact:authInfo>`, `</contact:check>`?!

Comment: I'm about to connect to a secure EPP server and send an XML request and then receive a response in XML format again.

I need to do this in PHP. So I need to connect to the EPP server on a specific port over TCP, using SSL Certificate (as this is the information I have so far, still waiting to whitelist my IP and send me the certificate).